# Python Tkinter grid inside grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a 2d map, and each map cell has another 5x5 cell.

I am able to generate the following 2d map:

[image]

Inside each block, I would like to create another smaller 3x3 grid cells, such that in each block there would be something like this:

[image]

mymap.py:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyMap():
    def __init__(self, master, i, j):
        self.text = StringVar()
        self.label = Label(master, textvariable = self.text, height = 5, width = 11, relief = RIDGE, bg = "gray30", fg = "white", font = "Helvetica 12")
        self.label.grid(row = i, column = j, sticky = W, pady = 1)
        self.row = i
        self.col = j
```

main.py

```
master = Tk()

[[MyMap(master, i, j) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: What that really means is that you have a 20x20 grid, with some extra padding every 5 rows and columns.  RIght?

Comment: inside every cell in `grid()` you can put `Frame` with own `grid()`

Comment: @TimRoberts I would like to have a fixed size grid e.g 4v4 grid. And each grid cell, I want it to show a 5v5 grid

Comment: @furas do you have some resources you can point me to? I tried adding frame, but it's drawing outside each grid

Comment: first you have to create `Frames` with `grid()`  4x4 and later in every frame use `grid()` to put `myMap` in `3x3`. And every `myMap` has to use `frame` as master

Comment: it maybe simpler to first use Frame to create new class with grid() 3x3 and later reuse it to create grid 4x4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could crate grid 4x4 using Frames and in every frame you could put your `MyMap` in grid 3x3.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

class MyMap():
    def __init__(self, master, i, j, text='?'):
        self.text = tk.StringVar(master, value=text)
        self.label = tk.Label(master, textvariable=self.text, height=5, width=11, relief='ridge', bg="gray30", fg="white", font="Helvetica 12")
        self.label.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='w', pady=1, padx=1)
        self.row = i
        self.col = j
        
root = tk.Tk()

for outer_row in range(4):
    for outer_col in range(4):
        
        f = tk.Frame(root)
        f.grid(row=outer_row, column=outer_col, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        for inner_row in range(3):
            for inner_col in range(3):
                text = inner_row*3 + inner_col
                MyMap(f, inner_row, inner_col, text)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Brilliant! Is there a way to convert the loops into list comprehension so the information can be maintained?

Comment: I don't know if it can be converted to  list comprehension but it would create less readable code - so I prefer this version